# Japanese literature had begun in the late nineteenth century. (tense)

Tags: tense

> Japanese literature had begun in the late nineteenth century.

> Japanese literature begun in the late nineteenth century.

Which one is more idiomatic? My question would be focused on 'in the late nineteenth century': it could be used with 'had pp'

Comment: Without the context, I see no reason to use the Past Perfect tense here.

Comment: I am puzzled, because I thought that the earliest literary works in Japan were created a very long time before the 'late nineteenth century'.

Comment: The second version should be _began_, not _begun_.

Comment: Whether or not to use a Perfect verb form depends *entirely* on the surrounding narrative context. ***Which isn't provided,*** so there's no meaningful question to answer here. With over 3000 rep points, ***this*** OP should be well aware of that.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the tense 'setting' of the context. Use *had become* when you relate the beginning of Japanese literature to another moment in the past, and use *began* when you relate it to the present.

For example, you can add your sentence after this assertion from [TimeOut](https://www.timeout.com/tokyo/art/evolution-of-japanese-art-from-modern-to-contemporary-art):

> The creative explosion of Japanese art in the 20th century happened against a backdrop of a nation throwing off the cloak of isolation and embracing the world. ***Japanese literature had begun in the late nineteenth century.***

Answer (score 2):

To me, the first needs further expansion. It doesn't stand well alone, because it seems hard to imagine no-one wrote books in Japan before then.

> Japanese literature had begun in the late nineteenth century to explore overseas cultures and ideas.

The second should be 'began' not begun. It requires no comparison, but it's still hard to imagine it could be true.

> Japanese literature began in the late nineteenth century.

This still leaves me wondering why no-one was writing before then.
Unless you're going to go on and explain that in fact Japan had nothing that could be termed 'literature' before that time, it feels at best an incorrect claim.

Perhaps you mean it gained a fresh impetus after co-mingling with other cultures following a period of isolation…

> Japanese literature truly began in the late nineteenth century, after the borders were further opened to trade & visitors.

<sup>Don't quote me on any of this as historical *fact*, I only have a vague knowledge of Japan's history.</sup>